# getting data from another function to display highcharts in angular

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to display highcharts in my angular application
Below is my get_chart function which takes data from another function

```
function get_chart(data) {
    alert('hello..' + data);

        return {
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            chart: {
                height: 300,
                width: 500,
                type: 'column'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                console.log ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                data:  [ data ] 
            }]
        };
    }
```

Then I am trying to send data from

```
$scope.renderChart = function(measurement){
        $scope.showChart = false;

        restApp.getMeasurementForCompID(comp.id, measurement.id).then(function(data){
            console.log('getMeasurementForCompID data ');
            console.log(data);
            data = [10, 20];

            $scope.example_chart = get_chart(data);
            console.log($scope.example_chart);

            $scope.showChart = true;
        });

    }
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <highchart id="dash-chart" chart='example_chart'></highchart>
    </div>
```

Highcharts directive

```
myapp.directive('highchart', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch(function() { return attrs.chart; }, function() {

            if(!attrs.chart) return;

            var chart = scope.example_chart;

            console.log('loading chart');
            console.log(chart);
            element.highcharts(chart);

        });

    }
}
});
```

console

[image]

But I am unable to display the charts with values 10,20.
What might be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you initalize chart? Something like `new Highcharts.Chart()` or `$("container").highcharts()`?

Comment: yes am using highcharts for first time, please see my updated question i wrote a directive for highcharts

Comment: And what is your chart displaying? Try to change: `data:  [ data ] ` to `data: data`.

Comment: i did that but no use, my chart is not displaying at all

Comment: And do you have any errors in console? Do you see `'loading chart'` in console?

Comment: please see the console image i added to my question

Comment: Then you can see that: `console.log(chart);` return undefined, so there is no options for a chart, so chart won't be created.

Comment: @PawełFus so how to correct it? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by doing following

```
<div>
<highchart ng-if="showChart" id="dash-chart" chart='example_chart'></highchart>
</div>
```

Thank you